# DrawableButton in EditText to Show/Hide Password and change DrawableEnd

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

This is the `activity_register.xml` :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextTextPassword"
    android:layout_width="346dp"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_vpn_key"
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_visibility"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/password_hint"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextEmailAddress" />
```

So,

I have password `EditText`

[image: password edittext with drawable]

 When you click the `drawableEnd`, you should see the password and the drawable should change to another one, which then hides the password again.

I found tutorials where you can show the password -> worked
_________________________change the drawable -> didn't work 
But, I found no tutorial for a `onClickListener` inside a drawable for kotlin

**Problem short** 
Code to show the password if the drawable is clicked, and if it clicked another time the password hides again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is [`TextInputLayout`](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-fields/) from the Material Componenets.

Here's how you do it:

- Implement Material Library in your build.gradle(app) file as:

  ```
  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha01'
  ```
- Then, change the XML's EditText to

  ```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
      android:id="@+id/passwordLayout"
      style="@style/TextInputLayoutAppearanceFilled"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:hint="@string/password"

      app:endIconMode="password_toggle" //This is used to set the password toggle behavior

      app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_lock_black_24dp">

      <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
          android:id="@+id/password"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:inputType="textPassword"
          android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

  </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
  ```
- Then, Change the Style as you want in `styles.xml`:

  ```
   <style name="TextInputLayoutAppearanceFilled" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
   <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/HintText</item>
   <item name="helperTextTextAppearance">@style/HelperText</item>

   <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_grey</item>
   <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/color</item>
   <item name="hintTextColor">@color/color</item>
   <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/color</item>
   <item name="startIconTint">@color/color</item>
   <item name="endIconTint">@color/color</item>
   <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/white</item>

   <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">@dimen/_26sdp</item>
   <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">@dimen/_26sdp</item>
   <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">@dimen/_26sdp</item>
   <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">@dimen/_26sdp</item>

   <item name="boxStrokeWidthFocused">0dp</item>

   <!--This destroys the visible layout in layout editor so  first
   comment this out to design-->
   <!--<item name="boxStrokeWidth">0dp</item>-->

   <item name="hintEnabled">true</item>

   </style>
  ```
- Here's how the output will look like:

  [image]

The Password toggle will work exactly how you want it, also, the icon changes to the other one as well. You can further customize it as you want, have a look at the official documentation first - [`TextInputLayout`](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-fields/)

Comment: Thanks very much, i saw this site because of the icons but i didnt see that... thanks very much, i do appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [**`TextInputLayout`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextField.md) provided by the Material Components Library with the password toggle end icon:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/..."
        app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
        android:hint="Password">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            .../>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]